# Why does 1 == 1 == 1, but not 'A' == 'A' == 'A'

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

I'm trying to write a flexible query logic based on a config payload, e.g:

```
{
 "test": "( fieldA == fieldB == fieldC )"
}
```

When my app replaces 'fieldA', 'fieldB' and 'fieldC' value with text data, the result is always false.
This clearly has to do with me confusing the way javascript runs the comparison (it must have something to do with data types and math ordering), but can anyone explain this with a simple example for alphanumeric values?

e.g. 'John Smith' == 'John Smith' == 'John Smith' is always false;

Comment: Comparing a boolean to a string (or even a number) is strange to begin with.  What's the goal of this logic?

Comment: Because `true == 1`, but `true != 'John Smith'`

Comment: There's no comparison at all, `"( fieldA == fieldB == fieldC )"` is always `"( fieldA == fieldB == fieldC )"` ...

Comment: In any language that has to be rewritten to `fieldA == fieldB && fieldA == fieldC && fieldB == fieldC`

Comment: @Teemu the fact that OP has said "_result is always false_" indicates that there is some logic that interprets and evaluate the string

Comment: It's because of the order of operations, so `('A' == 'A')` which is `true` so if you did `'A' == 'A' == true` you get true, but `('A' == 'A') == 'A'` is not true because the last `'A'` is not equal to `true`...

Comment: Hi @David, i'm trying to write a 'codified' evaluation string as a rule. Each fieldX is a uniqueID and I'm trying to check if all 3 fieldX values are identical; i was hoping there was a short format/version for that logic

Answer (score 6):

`x == y == z` does not do what you think :

it translates to `(x == y) == z`.

With the quirks of javascript's `==` operator :

- `1 == 1` and `'A' == 'A'` both translate to `true`
- however : `true == 1` returns true, while `true == 'A'` doesn't

---

You probably want to rewrite your condition to :

```
(x == y) && (x == z)
```

and very probably want to use the unambiguous `===` operator :

```
(x === y) && (x === z)
```

to avoid pitfalls such as the one you falled upon (`true == 1` checks, but not `true === 1`)

Answer (score 0):

A==B==C or A==A==A is legally allowed.

But the problem is, A==C never happens or in your case fieldA==fieldC never happens. Hence this leads to ambiguity